# How to render a controller in a custom Twig extension using Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I've written a custom Twig function that should render some HTML. My first idea was to create a new Controller for the rendering logic and use that in the Twig extension. But it does not work as it throws this error when calling `{{ button() }}` in a template:

FATALERROREXCEPTION: ERROR: CALL TO A MEMBER FUNCTION GET() ON A NON-OBJECT IN /FOO/VENDOR/SYMFONY/SYMFONY/SRC/SYMFONY/BUNDLE/FRAMEWORKBUNDLE/CONTROLLER/CONTROLLER.PHP LINE 106

The Twig extensions basically work (I've already implemented some simple helpers not shown here).

The Controller (unnecessary code stripped):

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class ButtonController extends Controller {

    public function showAction()
    {
        [...]
        return $this->render(
            'AcmeDemoBundle:Default:button.html.twig', array($vars)
        );
    }
}
```

The Twig extension:

```
class AcmeExtension extends \Twig_Extension {

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('button', array($this, 'button'), array('is_safe' => array('html'))),
        );
    }

    public function button()
    {
        $controller = new ButtonController();
        return $controller->showAction();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not injecting the container appropriately. But my real question here is why you want to do this in a controller?

Comment: The Button is rendering a construct that has some more or less complex business logic in it. So I thought doing this in a controller that renders its own template should be the preferred way. What would you recommend instead?

Comment: That logic could probably just as well be implemented in another class or service.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want, when you call the `{{ button() }}` function, render a controller.

Why not doing a simple:

```
{{ render(controller('AcmeDemoBundle:Button:show')) }}
```

This avoid creating a tricky extension for such an easy task.

If you really, really want to call `{{ button() }}`, you can create a macro, such as:

```
{% macro button() %}
    {{ render(controller('AcmeDemoBundle:Button:show')) }}
{% endmacro %}
{% from _self.templateName import 'button' %}
```

And you can now use `{{ button() }}` on the same template.

Comment: The button rendering controller has some more logic in it. The variables it needs are not all available in the twig template the viewhelper is called.